# connecting to AWS RDS from nodejs local machine

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-rds

I have been getting connect ETIMEDOUT 172.31.97.43:5432 error while trying to test my nodejs express app with postgres database running on my local machine to connect to AWS RDS.

I have done the necessary settings on the AWS RDS like;

- setting Inbound and Outbounds rules to allow all trafic
- setting the publicly to Yes

MY Connection setup looks this in database.ts file:

```
import {Pool}  from "pg";

export const client = new Pool({
    host     : 'omerenma.cs6txkhiualn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user     : '********',
    password : '********',
    port     : 5432,
    connectionTimeoutMillis:30000
  })

client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
  
    console.log('Connected to database.');
  });



***client.end()***
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Any number of things could be wrong here depending on things like how your AWS VPC's are set up. Can you connect to the database in a postgres client like pgAdmin, Datagrip, or someting else?

Comment: See [How do I resolve problems when connecting to my Amazon RDS DB instance?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect). Add specifics of your DB and other security group rules if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Haven spent time going through my AWS RDS setup, I realized the following:

1  I had too many vpc that were conflicting with others
2  My security groups where also conflicting
3  My node version is 18+ and by default has an Ipv6 where as AWS RDS listens
to Ipv4
4  My inbound rules was not properly configured

Solutions:
1  I deleted all the vpc including the default vpc and created a new default
vpc
2  I configured my Inbound rules to listen for Ipv4 and Ipv6 and to also listen
for all traffic within ipv4 and ipv6.
3  I adjusted my security groups appropriately
This was the fix and my nodejs server can now connect to AWS RDS

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the vpc (default vpc as well) which in turn deletes  all the subnets and security groups and freshly setting up everything freshly

Things to keep in mind

1. The inbound rule should have **0.0.0.0/0**
2. The database instance should be **Publicly accessible**

**If nothing works delete the vpc and create a new one and then the above points**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).